# Asp.net core HttpsRedirectionMiddleware Failed to determine the https port for redirect

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to host an ASP.net Core Web Application in a windows service. I am able to create a self contained deployment and created the windows service. My web application is configured to have port 5000 for http and 5001 for https. Within the application , I use a HttpsRedirectMiddleware.

When I start the windows service , it is only possible to browse the web page over http and throws following error from the Https redirect middleware.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware Failed to
>   determine the https port for redirect.

Is there any extra configuration needed to expose a port for https communication?

[Github Code Sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/windows-service/samples/2.x/AspNetCoreService)

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 16):

[See the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for various ways of configuring a non-default HTTPS port.

Which approach suits your scenario best depends on how your application is set up and hosted. You could for example add a setting:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSetting("https_port", "5001")
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this warning on debug mode. You just need to "Enable SSL" and the warning goes away.

[image]

Or if you use IIS, you can edit the Advanced Settings to enable https.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same error. In my case, there were two profiles in the launchSettings.json file. I simply removed one of the profiles, which had the http and https URL.

```json
"profiles": {
  "https": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "swagger",
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7009;http://localhost:5195",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: You can start a specific profile with `dotnet watch -lp https`

Comment: *`I simply removed one of the profiles, which had the http and https URL.`* This works for using HTTP only, but now I can't debug HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because the https dev cert isn't trusted. Should be a better error message.

```bash
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Comment: *`dotnet dev-certs https --trust`* fixes Visual Studio's console warning, but I still can't hit the API via Postman.

Answer (score 2):

### This is for .NET 7.0

- Select the block of code for the HTTP profile.
- Use the command `Ctrl + X` to cut that block of code.
- Then use `Ctrl + Z` to paste it just as it was before you executed the step above.

**Run these commands**
`dotnet build`
`dotnet watch`

*Note that this is what I did and my development server was up and running again*

Comment: If this fixes things it's most likely that it's a rebuild or caching issue, a rebuild-all would be a faster way to eliminate that.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I Commented this line : app.UseHttpsRedirection();
in Program.cs to avoid redirect to https in not secure servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can have problems with areas. You will need to add to all controllers' area attributes. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99BPJ.png)
of my controller route

Example of the controller:

```cs
[Area("home")] //You need this
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Example of map controller route

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Home}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Answer (score -4):

Do the following changes in program.cs for .net 6

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();

}


app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).