# ASP.NET Core 6 - Integrationtest with Identity Provider/EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, integration-testing

I develop an example app using ASP.NET Core 6. This includes a simple user login and registration.

The integration test checks the login endpoint in the user controller.

My xUnitTest is based on
[Microsoft Integrationtest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequestDTO request)
{
    var response = await _user.Login(request);

    if (response.User == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Token))
    {
        _response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        _response.IsSuccess = false;
        _response.ErrorMessage.Add("incorrect username or password");

        return BadRequest(_response);
    }

    _response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    _response.IsSuccess = true;
    _response.Result = response;

    return Ok(_response);
}
```

The example test adds an user to a SQLite in-memory database and tests the login endpoint.

```
[Fact]
public async void Test1()
{
        LoginRequestDTO? responseModel;

        using (var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<AppDBContext>();

            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Seeding...");

                db.AppUser.Add(new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Name = "Admin Powers",
                    UserName = "admin@contoso.com",
                    Email = "admin@contoso.com",
                    PasswordHash = "MAKV2SPBNI99212",
                    NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN@CONTOSO.COM",
                    NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@CONTOSO.COM",
                    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                });

                db.SaveChanges();

                Console.WriteLine($"Players seeded: {db.AppUser.Count()}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Fehler Calcifer: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        LoginRequestDTO httpCont = new() { UserName = "admin@contoso.com", Password = "MAKV2SPBNI99212" };
        var test = JsonSerializer.Serialize(httpCont);
        var httpContent = new StringContent(test);
        var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/User/login", httpContent);

        //var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I expected an successful response but I get a "Bad Request" response.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

[The test host output](https://github.com/AK2083/Calcifer/blob/master/Calcifer/testhost_output.txt)

[Source - Github](https://github.com/AK2083/Calcifer)

Comment: Last line of your output says it all: 'Failed to determine the https port for redirect.' The issue is entirely unrelated to your db-/login-/test-code provided above. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724202/asp-net-core-httpsredirectionmiddleware-failed-to-determine-the-https-port-for-r) helps..

Comment: missing `appsettings`  configuration provided Source code from Git.

Comment: @SanchoPanza Accordingly your comment I change my code and this message doesn't appear. Hence, the Bad Request response remains in place.

Comment: Not too sure but I think your code causes json-serialization twice. First by calling 'JsonSerializer.Serialize(httpCont)', second time by calling '_client.PostAsJsonAsync(..)'. Try to ommit the first and just call '_client.PostAsJsonAsync(.., **httpCont**)'

Comment: I change the line to: var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/User/login", httpCont); Then I get this error: System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher`1.VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, String hashedPassword, String providedPassword)

Comment: But I think this was the error. Thank you 1000x